# How to have a getter bound to a function with boolean evaluation?

Tags: javascript, getter

I'd like to access the object's properties conditionally, but my code always returns `100` for `obj.stats.speed` for both `isCar = true` and `isCar = false`. What am I doing wrong? Thanks

```
var isCar = false;

var obj = { 
    car : {
        speed: 100,
        size: 1000
    },
    bike: {
        speed: 10,
        size: 20
    }
};

Object.defineProperty(obj, "stats", { get: function () { 

    if(isCar) {
        return car;
    } else {
        return bike;
    }

} });

console.log(obj.stats.speed); //returns 100 instead of 10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your `return` statement value.

```js
var isCar = false;

var obj = { 
    car : {
        speed: 100,
        size: 1000
    },
    bike: {
        speed: 10,
        size: 20
    }
};

Object.defineProperty(obj, "stats",{ get: function() { 
    if(isCar){
      return obj.car; //changed from car to obj.car
    }else{
      return obj.bike; //changed from bike to obj.bike
    }
 }
});

console.log(obj.stats.speed);
```